# replace image that contains certain text with new image

Tags: jquery

I'd like to use jQuery to find the image src and read if the img src contains the text "window-16x16.png"  , then replace that image. The url changes all the time but the image file name remains consistent.

```
<table id="league_chat" class="homepagemodule report" align="center" cellspacing="1">
    <caption>
        <span>
            League Chat 
            <a href="javascript:chat_window('http://www20.myfantasyleague.com/2014/chat?L=52761&COUNT=40');">
                <img width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="New Window" title="New Window" src="http://www20.myfantasyleague.com/window-16x16.png"></img>
            </a>
        </span>
    </caption>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('src').indexOf('window-16x16.png')){
    $(this).attr('src','new-path.png');
  }
}
```

Comment: It will check and change `src` of the first image on the page only.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/u5g1eu97/ it changed src of those img also which don't have `window-16x16.png` also

Comment: @Manwal because it's using 'img' The OP need to use $(this) as in the function...

Comment: Correct @C-linkNepal so you should improve your ans for future refrence

Comment: this is replacing every image on my page with the new image

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").each(function() {  
   var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
   if(imgsrc.indexOf('window-16x16.png')>-1){ //updated
      $(this).attr('src','new-img-src.png');
    }
  });
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/0hg1ejow/2/)

> **Note:** Code replacing only where img src contains the text
>   *"window-16x16.png"*

Comment: none of the above are working , they are replacing every image on the page with the new image

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
$('#league_chat').find('img[src$="window-16x16.png"]').prop('src', function() {
    this.src = this.src.replace('window-16x16.png', 'window-32x32.png');
});
```

It will change `src` of all images which `src` attribute end with `window-16x16.png`.